# Can Groovy machine connect to Indigo master?

Tags: ros, multiplemachines

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to communicate two different machines using ROS, but they have different ROS version. Is there any compatibility issue?
I have a robot installed with Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS Groovy, and a laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo.
The two machines are connected by an Ethernet cable. I could ping each other from both machines and the ROS_MASTER_URI variables are exported to be the same. However, my robot cannot find the master node on my laptop.

I guess it is due to compatibility issue between the two ROS versions. Is there any solution besides reinstall the whole system? Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234174/can-groovy-machine-connect-to-indigo-master?/) by [fina12](https://answers.ros.org/users/26838/fina12/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nodes from Groovy should be able to connect to an Indigo ROS master, and Indigo nodes should be able to connect to the Groovy ROS master.

There have been some message format changes between Groovy and Indigo, so there will be message types and topics that don't work between nodes of different versions. You'll usually see an error message about MD5sum mismatches from one or both nodes involved when this happens.

You should consult the [Hydro migration guide](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration) and [Indigo migration guide](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Migration) for specific package changes between versions.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [curranw](https://answers.ros.org/users/17736/curranw/) on 2016-05-12**:
Just to add an interesting note to this: You can even do this with different operating systems. We did this when the Kinect 2 had Windows-only drivers. As long as the messages have the same format, everything works fine.

**Comment by [fina12](https://answers.ros.org/users/26838/fina12/) on 2016-05-12**:
Problem solved. Thanks a lot!